# Why is asmcrypto giving a runtime error when calling AES_CCM encrypt?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I've installed the asmcrypto library, per the instructions at https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js#build--test

I've run the tests and all pass.

I now have an HTML test page which includes:

```
    <script src="asmcrypto.js"></script>
```

and some JavaScript which attempts to use the AES CCM cipher mode:

```
    encrypted = asmCrypto.AES_CCM.encrypt(payload, key, nonce, [], 4);
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined
```

I looked in the generated asmcrypto.js and I don't see AES_CCM anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

On the other hand, this works suggesting I've installed correctly:

```
    console.log("SHA256:"+asmCrypto.SHA256.hex("hello"));
```

Comment: Client side encryption is entirely pointless. It's like locking all your money in a safe and leaving the key in the lock. Unless this is node?

Comment: This isn't "production code". It's more of an educational resource, where some crypto is one of the ingredients. Web technology is being used to provide a platform agnostic platform. That said, this is rather off topic.